# Form is not displayed when the binding data is empty

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to display the form,i had with it but when i have emoty data the form is not displayed,Can someone please suggest help.
My Template,

```
<form  class="nobottommargin" *ngIf="details"   [formGroup]="form"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" name="template-contactform">
<div class="col-sm-12 nopadding socialaddress">
    <div class="col-sm-12 formpaddingcss">
       <h3 class = "headingfontcss">SOCIAL ADDRESS</h3>
     </div>  
                </div>   
                <div class="input-group divcenter">
                    <input type="email" tooltip="Enter Facebook url" [tooltipDisabled]="false" [tooltipAnimation]="true"
                    tooltipPlacement="top" name="widget-subscribe-form-email" [formControl]="form.controls['facebook']" [(ngModel)]="details.facebook"  class="form-control required email formcontrolheight" placeholder="Facebook" aria-required="true">
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

The above form is not displayed when "details" are empty,i had tried a lot but still no result.

my ts,

```
          export class Social {
         message: any;
         http: Http;
         details: IDetails[];
         form: FormGroup;

       constructor(fbld: FormBuilder, http: Http, private _service: GetAllList,public toastr: ToastsManager) {
    this.details = []
    this.http = http;
      this._service.getList()
        .subscribe(details => this.details = details);


    this.form = fbld.group({
        facebook: ['', Validators.required],
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a *ngIf directive pointing at details on the form element. If details is empty, JS will interpret that as false and not render the form.

Comment: so,i should remove it?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you want it. Is there any condition where you wouldn't want your form to show? That's what the NgIf would support. Otherwise, yes, remove it.

Comment: Eric,i didnt have any condition to hide from but here when i had data form is displayed with data and no there is no data empty from is not displaying instead it is hiding.

Comment: when i removed ngIf it says error---------Cannot read property 'facebook' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Remove `*ngIf` directive from your form and in your component set value of variable facebook to empty string.

Comment: Stevan,still no use ,i edited my code pls hav a look

Comment: I also think you don't need `[(ngModel)]="details.facebook"`, try removing that.

Comment: this is the error after removing it,Cannot find control ''"

Comment: Change the following:

`facebook: ['', Validators.required]`

to

`facebook: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])`

Also, in input of your form add `[control]="form.controls.facebook">`

Comment: My bad, you need to add `formControlName="facebook"`, not `[control]="form.controls.facebook"`.

Comment: but i am subscribing my data to details how can i append data to form by removing ngModel

Comment: Well, you have `onSubmit(form)` method, you can do anything you want with your data there. First you can check if you get your data correctly with `console.log(form.value)`. If you are, you can place input data to your details variable like this: `this.details.facebook = form.value.facebook`.

Comment: Stefan,i didnt understood can u edit my code please.